# Как получить данные из сериализованной строки при помощи Python?

Tags: python, десериализация

Есть данные подобного вида, полученные от БД:

```
[('a:5:{s:4:"NAME";s:10:"Агния";s:9:"LAST_NAME";s:0:"";s:5:"EMAIL";s:41:"a72536c75535422d86e36f2b5a0a23eb@fake.com";s:4:"CODE";s:4:"5433";s:7:"MESSAGE";s:77:"Вы запросили ваши регистрационные данные.";}',), ('a:5:
{s:4:"NAME";s:12:"Демьян";s:9:"LAST_NAME";s:0:"";s:5:"EMAIL";s:41:"ae45d5a28d224642a2607b152e431a67@fake.com";s:4:"CODE";s:4:"1968";s:7:"MESSAGE";s:77:"Вы запросили ваши регистрационные данные.";}',),  ('a:5:{s:4:"NAME";s:10:"Раиля";s:9:"LAST_NAME";s:0:"";s:5:"EMAIL";s:41:"60c7c2fa242f48c7bb28ce8d3c02bb7b@fake.com";s:4:"CODE";s:4:"6745";s:7:"MESSAGE";s:77:"Вы запросили ваши регистрационные данные.";}',)]
```

Насколько понял, это сериализованная строка. Как мне получить данные полей EMAIL и CODE с использованием python?

Comment: Не знаю что это за формат данных, но на вид как список кортежей со строковыми элементами. Как вы пытались получить данные? Приведите примеры вашего кода. Вы должны понимать, что писать код за вас тут никто не собирается.

Comment: Пробовал использовать json.load() и json.loads(), напрямую передавая им строку. Код был черновой, его не сохранил. Пока пришёл к выводу, что буду получать строку и далее через использование регулярных выражений получать нужные данные. Изначально же думал, что есть какие-то библиотеки, которые могли бы распарсить такой формат.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не сериализованная строка, а чёрти что. У сериализации должны быть правила, а тут ну очень много `:`, что не под одну разметку не ложится. К формату надо приводить, чтобы десериализовать.

Но не будем о грустном, вопрос был в том как достать данные, и нет ничего невозможного для [регулярные-выражения](/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f):

```python
import re
from pprint import pprint

s = # сюда ту ебурдень, что Вы выложили в вопросе.

terms = ['EMAIL', 'CODE']
result = {term: [] for term in terms}
for i in s:
    for term in terms:
        pattern = r'"('+term+r')"[^"]+"([^"]+)'
        result[re.search(pattern, i[0]).group(1)].append(re.search(pattern, i[0]).group(2))
pprint(result)
```

###### Вывод:

```console
{'CODE': ['5433', '1968', '6745'],
 'EMAIL': ['a72536c75535422d86e36f2b5a0a23eb@fake.com',
           'ae45d5a28d224642a2607b152e431a67@fake.com',
           '60c7c2fa242f48c7bb28ce8d3c02bb7b@fake.com']}
```

### Парсинг всей строки

Лишний раз повторюсь, что на входных данная полная ебурда, но и это при особом желании и терпении распарсить и привести к формату можно.

#### Вариант 1

```python
temp = re.sub(r'[a-z]:\d+:', r'', str(s))
temp = re.sub(r';(.*?);', r':\1,', temp)
temp = re.sub(r',}', r'}', temp)
temp = re.sub(r"\(\'|\),|\|,'|\'|,\)", r'', temp)
json.loads(temp)
```

```console
[{'NAME': 'Агния',
  'LAST_NAME': '',
  'EMAIL': 'a72536c75535422d86e36f2b5a0a23eb@fake.com',
  'CODE': '5433',
  'MESSAGE': 'Вы запросили ваши регистрационные данные.'},
 {'NAME': 'Демьян',
  'LAST_NAME': '',
  'EMAIL': 'ae45d5a28d224642a2607b152e431a67@fake.com',
  'CODE': '1968',
  'MESSAGE': 'Вы запросили ваши регистрационные данные.'},
 {'NAME': 'Раиля',
  'LAST_NAME': '',
  'EMAIL': '60c7c2fa242f48c7bb28ce8d3c02bb7b@fake.com',
  'CODE': '6745',
  'MESSAGE': 'Вы запросили ваши регистрационные данные.'}]
```

#### Вариант 2

⚠ С `eval()` надо быть [очень осторожным](https://habr.com/ru/post/221937/).

```python
temp = re.sub(r'([a-z]:\d+)', r'"\1"', str(s))
temp = re.sub(r'(?<=");', ',', temp)
temp = re.sub(r',}', r'}', temp)
temp = re.sub(r"\(\'|\),|\|,'|\'|,\)", r'', temp)
temp = re.sub(r"(\[|,\s)", r'\1{', temp)
temp = re.sub(r"(\]|,\s)", r'}\1', temp)
eval(temp)
```

```console
[{'a-5': {'s-4': '5433',
   's-10': 'Агния',
   's-9': 'LAST_NAME',
   's-0': '',
   's-5': 'EMAIL',
   's-41': 'a72536c75535422d86e36f2b5a0a23eb@fake.com',
   's-7': 'MESSAGE',
   's-77': 'Вы запросили ваши регистрационные данные.'}},
 {'a-5': {'s-4': '1968',
   's-12': 'Демьян',
   's-9': 'LAST_NAME',
   's-0': '',
   's-5': 'EMAIL',
   's-41': 'ae45d5a28d224642a2607b152e431a67@fake.com',
   's-7': 'MESSAGE',
   's-77': 'Вы запросили ваши регистрационные данные.'}},
 {'a-5': {'s-4': '6745',
   's-10': 'Раиля',
   's-9': 'LAST_NAME',
   's-0': '',
   's-5': 'EMAIL',
   's-41': '60c7c2fa242f48c7bb28ce8d3c02bb7b@fake.com',
   's-7': 'MESSAGE',
   's-77': 'Вы запросили ваши регистрационные данные.'}}]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Воспользуюсь первым вариантом и изучу второй

Comment: @oblako_123 регулярные выражения, конечно, проще писать чем читать  Если будут вопросы, пишите.